# Custom cursor in jQuery datepicker trigger icon

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is there a way to show a custom CUR cursor when the mouse is over the trigger icon of a standard jQuery datepicker? I'm trying this solution, but it doesn't work and don't know how to solve the problem:

```
$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','url(img/circle_cursor.cur)');
});
```

If I declare 'pointer' instead of the url, it works perfectly, but I'd like to use a fully custom CUR cursor file...

Answer (score -1):

Why use jquery when you can achieve the same in plain css:

```
.ui-datepicker-trigger {
    cursor: url(img/circle_cursor.cur);
}
```

Also make sure the path to your image is correct and the image size is at most 32x32.

Comment: Ok, I've found my problem: the custom png is larger than 32x32, this is why I wasn't able to have it visible on the page. I'll need to find an alternative way to implement my custom cursor, perhaps a floating div following the mouse pointer...